# how to update multiple users location and update markers also on google map after 15 seconds

Tags: android

hi friends i want to get location of other users from the web service i did it and now i want to locate this new latitue and longitue to google map and update its location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a location manager, and then write your code to onStatusChanged method, you can see the documentation here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

It is documented under Requesting Location Updates title